# Javascript reload page after loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript code. What i want is after i run this loop, i want to reload the page to some other page. However the code below is reloading the page even before my data is sent.

Edit: I added send file to server code as requested

```
function handleFileUpload(files,obj)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
   {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', files[i]);
        fd.append( 'date_taken', files[i].lastModifiedDate )
        var status = new createStatusbar(obj,files[i]); 
        //Using this we can set progress.
        status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name,files[i].size);
        sendFileToServer(fd,status);

   }
   location.reload()

}

function sendFileToServer(formData,status)
{
    var uploadURL ="<?php echo base_url('test/upload'); ?>"; //Upload URL
    var extraData ={}; //Extra Data.
    var jqXHR=$.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
            var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhrobj.upload) {
                    xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                        var percent = 0;
                        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                        var total = event.total;
                        if (event.lengthComputable) {
                            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                        }
                        //Set progress
                        status.setProgress(percent);
                    }, false);
                }
            return xhrobj;
        },
    url: uploadURL,
    type: "POST",
    contentType:false,
    processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            status.setProgress(100);

            $("#status1").append("File upload Done<br>");         
        }
    }); 

    status.setAbort(jqXHR);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for sendFileToServer to your question?  My guess is that sendFileToServer is doing an asynchronous call, and you need to wait for its callback before doing location.reload()

Comment: You should not reload the page after the "send" loop, you should reload the page when all files uploaded. I think you are doing ajax to upload your files in sendFileToServer(). You need wait the server's response, check if all files' status are uploaded every time one file uploaded. If all, do reload.

Comment: I have added send file to server code

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous which means it continues to execute the code even the request is send some where, you have to wait until the files are uploaded, for e.x using [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) when you send an ajax call, you can handle it with **.done**(which means the request is completed) and now you ready for next action, in your case reload or what ever, hope this helped to you.